Index of duplicated values in pandas
I'm using pandas in python and using the duplicated(keep=False) I've made a check between the values of a same dataframe column. So I'm getting as result:
5063     True
5064     True
5065     True
5066    False
5067    False
        ...  
5310    False
5311    False
5312     True
5313    False
5314    False

Now I'd like to find the index of the true values. So I've thought that this could work
duplicateRowsDF = df.duplicated(keep=False)
for j in range (0, len(duplicateRowsDF)):
    attempt=str(duplicateRowsDF.iloc[j])
    if attempt=="True":
        duplicated_index=duplicateRowsDF.index

but I'm getting
Index([5063, 5064, 5065, 5066, 5067, 5068, 5069, 5070, 5071, 5072,
   ...
   5305, 5306, 5307, 5308, 5309, 5310, 5311, 5312, 5313, 5314],
  dtype='int64', length=252)

while I'm aiming to have an "array" made with 5063 5064 5065 5312.
I've also tried the code df[df.index.duplicated(keep=False)] but it seems not providing me what I'm expecting.

Simply perform boolean indexing on the index:
out = duplicateRowsDF.index[duplicateRowsDF]

Or, without intermediate:
out = df.index[df.duplicated(keep=False)]


the first works for me!thanks

@martinmistere both should work the same way in theory ;)

You can filter index values in boolean indexing - use this solution instead your attempt:
out = df.index[df.duplicated(keep=False)]


i'm getting this as output Index([], dtype='int64')

@martinmistere - You are right, I have typo.

If you want to find the indices of the rows where the value is duplicated, you can use the index attribute along with boolean indexing.
true_indices = df[df['your_column_name'].duplicated(keep=False)].index.tolist()

with this approach you create a subset of the DataFrame containing only the duplicated rows based on the specified column. Then, will retrieve the indices of these duplicated rows. Finally the output will be a list of indices where the value is True. This list contains the indices you're looking for!
